# how to include a file inside common files reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have two common files such as `header.js` and `footer.js`, I want to include another `index.js` file inside those common files.

I am probably new to `ReactJs`. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

it would be great if anybody could help me out. thank you in advance!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Common from './App.js'

import Index from './components/home/index.js';
import Header from './components/common/header.js';
import Footer from './components/common/footer.js';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>


        <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />

      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Not sure If I understand correctly, but you can always create a component that wraps Header and Footer together.

Comment: @MichałLach can you please take a look at this link --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63067229/react-manipulate-filter-effect-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put an example for you, it will help you to understand that.

first, create a `root.js` file for example

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import HeaderComponent from './components/header/headerComponent';
export default class Root extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
    }

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                <HeaderComponent />
                <div className="container-fluid"> 
                    { this.props.children}  
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and in your `router.js` do it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { Router ,  Route , browserHistory  } from 'react-router';
// child components -->
import RootComponent from './root';
import EmployeesComponent from './components/employees/employeesComponent';
import ProfileComponent from './components/profile/profileComponent';
import NotFoundComponent from './components/notFound/notFoundComponent';

class RouterComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { current:false   }; 
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route  component={RootComponent}> 
                    <Route   path="/" component={EmployeesComponent} /> 
                    <Route   path="employees" component={EmployeesComponent} /> 
                    <Route   path="profile" component={ProfileComponent} /> 
                    <Route   path="*" component={NotFoundComponent} status={404} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default RouterComponent;
```

Comment: @xxnora could you say where is your problem, or do you want I explain it more for you?

Comment: can you please take a look at this link --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63067229/react-manipulate-filter-effect-dynamically